# What is the network effect of disjointed node software versions?

Tags: iri-node

A new update for IOTA has been released for nodes which is meant to improve network speed and add a new feature, promote, to replace re-attach.

Let's say 30% of nodes have updated to it. What happens to the other 70% of nodes that haven't updated, and are they a burden on the network that cause congestion? If not, how does the network efficiently handle the discrepancy?

Comment: Can we focus this question on a specific feature and include what that feature would require of wallets and nodes?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit

Comment: hmm, I never realized how bare bones the iota release notes are...

Comment: More relevant in this update was the more rigorous transaction validation, which resulted in getting lots of "dropped transactions" in the newer nodes from the older ones (see https://iota.stackexchange.com/q/790/134). For "promote" I guess the number of end-users not updating their wallet is a  greater burden than the full nodes that are not updated.

For manually added neighbors, nodes may "prod" them to update, but with Nelson, no idea...